# tabla html con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-tabla

Quiero obtener una tabla como el de la imagen, pero los titulos EFR y EFA no se acomodan bien, y como obtener la ultima fila con un poco de espacio?

Tambien quisiera mejorar el codigo, es mucho codigo para una simple tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.class = "display";
table.id = "example";
var thead = document.createElement('thead');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var th1 = document.createElement('th');
var th2 = document.createElement('th');
var th3 = document.createElement('th');

var texto1 = document.createTextNode("usuario");
var texto2 = document.createTextNode("EFA");
var texto3 = document.createTextNode("EFR");
th1.appendChild(texto1);
th2.appendChild(texto2);
th3.appendChild(texto3);
tr.appendChild(th1);
tr.appendChild(th2);
tr.appendChild(th3);
thead.appendChild(tr);
table.appendChild(thead);

var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

for (var indice = 0; indice < 5; indice++) {

  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  var texto1 = document.createTextNode('hola');
  td.appendChild(texto1);
  td.className = "info";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  var td = document.createElement('td');
  var td11 = document.createElement('td');
  var td12 = document.createElement('td');

  var elLink = document.createTextNode('datos');
  var elLink2 = document.createTextNode('datos');
  td11.appendChild(elLink);
  td12.appendChild(elLink2);
  tr.appendChild(td11);
  tr.appendChild(td12);

  var td = document.createElement('td');
  var td11 = document.createElement('td');
  var td12 = document.createElement('td');

  var elLink = document.createTextNode('datos');
  var elLink2 = document.createTextNode('datos');
  td11.appendChild(elLink);
  td12.appendChild(elLink2);
  tr.appendChild(td11);
  tr.appendChild(td12);

  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
tbody.appendChild(tr);
table.appendChild(tbody);
document.getElementById("tabla").appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="tabla"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo sería necesario añadir algunos atributos para que coincida con la imagen, por ejemplo el `colspan=2`  a su segundo y tercer `th`  y el `border` a la tabla con [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```
th2.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
```

El margen no es posible ya que para un `tr` no es aplicable como lo dicen en la [documentación](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#propdef-margin) , podría hacer algo no sé si sea lo más adecuado *(sin css)* pero se me ocurre añadir `tr` vacías para simular el espacio cuando llegue al final es decir que indice sea igual a 4 , *está claro que su código se puede mejorar pero solo tomé referencia su avance para dar solución*

```js
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.class = "display";
table.setAttribute('border', '1');
table.id = "example";
var thead = document.createElement('thead');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var th1 = document.createElement('th');
var th2 = document.createElement('th');
th2.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
var th3 = document.createElement('th');
th3.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
var texto1 = document.createTextNode("usuario");
var texto2 = document.createTextNode("EFA");
var texto3 = document.createTextNode("EFR");
th1.appendChild(texto1);
th2.appendChild(texto2);
th3.appendChild(texto3);
tr.appendChild(th1);
tr.appendChild(th2);
tr.appendChild(th3);

thead.appendChild(tr);
table.appendChild(thead);

var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

for (var indice = 0; indice < 5; indice++) {

  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  var texto1 = document.createTextNode('hola');
  td.appendChild(texto1);
  td.className = "info";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  var td = document.createElement('td');
  var td11 = document.createElement('td');
  var td12 = document.createElement('td');

  var elLink = document.createTextNode('datos');
  var elLink2 = document.createTextNode('datos');
  td11.appendChild(elLink);
  td12.appendChild(elLink2);
  tr.appendChild(td11);
  tr.appendChild(td12);

  var td = document.createElement('td');
  var td11 = document.createElement('td');
  var td12 = document.createElement('td');

  var elLink = document.createTextNode('datos');
  var elLink2 = document.createTextNode('datos');
  td11.appendChild(elLink);
  td12.appendChild(elLink2);
  tr.appendChild(td11);
  tr.appendChild(td12);
  if(indice===4){
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var tr1 = document.createElement('tr');
      tbody.appendChild(tr1);
    }
  }
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

table.appendChild(tbody);
document.getElementById("tabla").appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="tabla"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

En lo personal no soy muy fanatico de crear etiquetas con `document.createElement`, se me hace mas facil crear una cadena html para incluir cualquier etiqueta y modificarlo con la propiedad `innerHTML`.

**Por Ejemplo**

```js
 var html="<table border=1>";
 html+="<thead>";
 html+="<tr>";
 html+="<th> usuario </th>";
 html+="<th colspan=2;> EFA </th>";
 html+="<th colspan=2;> EFR </th> </tr></thead>";
    html+="<tbody>";
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
     html+="<tr><td>hola</td><td>datos1</td><td>datos2</td><td>datos3</td><td>datos4</td></tr>";
    }
    html+="</tbody>";
    html+="</table>";
 document.getElementById("tabla").innerHTML=html;
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabla"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//aqui el script
</script>
</body>
</html>
```